# Spring app across multiple servers

Tags: java, spring

I would like to implement an application which would span multiple app servers. The idea is that I would put different services on different machines, for instance, a billing service on one, and a booking service on the other. So if the billing server is down, you can still view all the booking information that is not dependent on billing information. It is imperative that the booking of tickets that requires billing services be transactional (across 2 data sources).

How would you go about this in Spring? Spring integration? or something else?

Thanks in advance guys. Any other input regarding the architecture is also very appreciated.

Comment: You'll need underlying RDBMS which will provide transactions and some kind of distributed cache, like Infinispan.

Comment: Spring integration isn't essential for such kind of project. Spring integration is set of types which support _Pipes-and-filters application architecture_ and it's better to be used inside single JVM, not accros several JVMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally using a Java EE container is best practice for this sort of thing. JBoss and Glassfish are open source application servers and solve exactly the problems that you are looking at.

Spring is one option for configuring applications like this, that span multiple app servers. Send me a message if you would like any extra info on this.